# How Array colorName[] changes value with variable i

Tags: android

```
String colorName [] = {"White", "Blue", "Red"};

for(int i =0; i<3 ; i++)
{
    Log.d("Favourite Colors", "" + colorName[i]);
}
```

How colorName[i] change value with Array?

Comment: Because the value of `i` changes?

Comment: Sir i got your point. I'm still in as how "colorName[i]" access "array value" as "variable i" is integer????

Answer (score 1):

`String colorName [] = {"White", "Blue", "Red"};`

You are initializing a `String` array which contains White, Blue and Red. In array's the index starts with 0 so `White` becomes 0th val, `Blue` becomes 1st and `Red` becomes 2nd element.

Now the code :

```
for(int i =0; i<3 ; i++)
    {
        Log.d("Favourite Colors", "" + colorName[i]);
    }
```

This basically runs a loop from 0 to 2, so when you print `colorName[0]` it will print White and so on.

Anyway, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sir i got your point. I'm still in as how "colorName[i]" access "array value" as "variable i" is integer???? –

Comment: Let's say you have to print `White`, you will print the variable `colorName[0]`. Right? So, instead of writing `colorName[0]`, `colorName[1]` and `colorName[2]`inside loop, you will run a loop from `0` to `2` and inside that write `colorName[i]`.

Comment: 'Thanks sir, for letting me grab your helpful knowledge. Sir what's the theory behind this logic as "variable i" is accessing "array value"??

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info on what are you trying to achieve here. Also i would re write your code like this

```
 for(int i =0; i<colorName.length ; i++)
    {
        Log.d("Favourite Colors", "" + colorName[i]);
    }
```